# Movie starts playing automatically?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have added a movie to my view and it simply starts playing automatically, does anyone know how to stop this?

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"LAN_S9" ofType:@"mp4"];

    if (moviePath)
    {
        NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

        [[moviePlayer view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 200)];  // frame must match parent view
    }

    [self.view addSubview: [moviePlayer view]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats simple:

```
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
```

Comment: or the ObjC way.. [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a view of MPMoviePlayerController into your view because the MPMoviePlayerController always require full screen mode to play and it will auto jump into that mode.

So, you can extract an image from the film and then show the image with a nice Play button so user can tap on the button to view the video

Comment: thats not true for iOS 3.2 and later, especially for iPad it is possible to play video in a subview without fullscreen

Comment: ah ok, I didn't test it well. Are you sure that with iphone4, it is ok to not play fullscreen?